# JScrollPane vertical scrollbar too wide

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, grouplayout, preferredsize

I'm using Netbeans GUI Builder to create a GUI app (so all the code generated is by Netbeans).

Everything looks fine in the Preview Design, but when I run the app, the JScrollPane displays badly...

[image: Default GUI]

...as you can see, only half of the scrollbar is visible.

I have tried manually setting the JScrollBar for the JScrollPane, using my own method:

```
jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBar(getScrollBarForScrollPane());
```

But that gives this result...

[image: New GUI]

Maybe there is some property on the JScrollBar or JScrollPane that I need to change?

I have been researching this for ages, so am hoping someone has some suggestions! :)

Here is my entire code...

```
package uk.co.mobilewebexpert.myappmonitor;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyAppMonitorJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private final ImageIcon greenIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/green_light.jpg"));
    private final ImageIcon amberIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/amber_light.jpg"));
    private final ImageIcon redIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/red_light.jpg"));

    /**
     * Creates new form MyAppMonitorJFrame
     */
    public MyAppMonitorJFrame() {
        initComponents();

        DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER);
        rightRenderer.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 21));
        for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            jTable1.getColumn(jTable1.getColumnName(i)).setHeaderRenderer(rightRenderer);
            jTable1.getColumn(jTable1.getColumnName(i)).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);

        }
        //jTable1.getTableHeader().setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11));


        DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{greenIcon, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"});


        jScrollPane1.setInsets
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("MYOB");

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Status Summary", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel6.setText("Total");
        jLabel6.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel7.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/green_light_2.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Online");
        jLabel7.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel8.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/amber_light_2.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("Suspect");
        jLabel8.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/red_light_2.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("Offline");
        jLabel9.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel10.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("?");

        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("?");

        jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel3.setText("?");

        jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel4.setText("?");

        jLabel5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 59, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 60, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap()));
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(jLabel6)
            .addComponent(jLabel7)
            .addComponent(jLabel8)
            .addComponent(jLabel9)
            .addComponent(jLabel10))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addComponent(jLabel5))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Search", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N

        jLabel11.setText("Enter device serial number");

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Go");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel11)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jTextField1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)))
            .addContainerGap()));
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel11)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jButton1))));

        jScrollPane1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Device Details", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N
        jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBar(getScrollBarForScrollPane());

        jTable1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(254, 254, 254));
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][]{
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null}
        },
            new String[]{
            "Serial Number", "Device Name", "Status", "Current Uptime", "Current Downtime", "Last Known Uptime"
        }));
        jTable1.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(254, 254, 254));
        jTable1.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
        jTable1.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jScrollPane2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Log", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12))); // NOI18N
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
            .addContainerGap()));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 328, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap()));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyAppMonitorJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyAppMonitorJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyAppMonitorJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyAppMonitorJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyAppMonitorJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public javax.swing.JScrollBar getScrollBarForScrollPane() {
        int width = 50; //set extremely large to exaggerate the issue
        javax.swing.JScrollBar jScrollBar = new javax.swing.JScrollBar(javax.swing.JScrollBar.VERTICAL);
        jScrollBar.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(width, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        return jScrollBar;
    }
// Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: That's why I hate using GUI-designer for writing swing applications.

Comment: I have tried building with JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 .

Comment: Eng, I've found the GUI Builder to be really useful (much better than banging my head against the wall with layout managers), but it's just this particular problem which is getting me.

Comment: @user What is the wrong with the first screen shot? I see the full scroll bar is shown

Comment: @user1617737 But it is really bad in terms of maintainability and code-readability, besides not understanding the swing well (specially if you want to customize the components).

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I don't think so. If the GUI builder of NetBeans is not appreciated, you can try `JFromDesigner`. They actually save your time much times than manually writing a `Layout`-based design

Comment: @Eng.Fouad explain to me how this is an issue with using a form editor. The JScrollPane is a self contained component, it's scroll bars are managed by it internally

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's true that JScrollPane is a self contained component, but it is affected by the other components such as its parent container.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad how are the scroll bars effected by anything outside the scroll pane? The are managed and laid out by the scroll pane, the only way I can see this effect being caused is if the scroll panes layout manager is changed (and I'm not sure if it can be)

Comment: @Desolator It saves me some time but I will lose other stuff as I said above. It is a trade-off. I think GUI-designer is suitable for mockups or small swing applications such as a small calculator.

Comment: @Desolator The full length of the scrollbar is shown, but the left hand side of it has been clipped visually.

Comment: @user1617737 try removing/resting the borders around the scroll panes to here defaults

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I've just been playing around with that, but all I've managed to do so far is make the scrollbar disappear - e.g., like with jScrollPane1.setBorder(null);. Can you recommend some code?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I'm working on a application with well over a million lines of code and use netbeans form designer as our primary entry point for most of our UI code. It's faster and simpler then hand coding much of the UI. Don't get me wrong, I do a lot if hand coded UI work as well, but when your trying to get a lay out cut out quickly, they are time saver. I agree, though, they re a tool and you should have a good understanding of how layout managers work in the first place. Plus, I never use GropuLayout, it goes wrong to way to quickly. After 12 years of UI coding, I have better things to ;)

Comment: @user1617737 don't set it to null, reset it. In netbeans right click the border property of the scroll pane a click rest default value

Comment: @user1617737: No, GUI Builder tools for Java are not accepted. It doesn't matter whether it is netbeans or something else. As you can already see, it is not supporting any good coding concepts. See how it calls components, each and every time it calls to the complete package! These GUI builders do follow group layout, which is not user friendly. Even researches clearly say this is one of worst practices. To be honest, this practice is rejected from GOOD java community. Java is differ from .NET, where this is acceptable, and that is one reason Java gained Honor among programmers than .NET

Comment: @Yohan WHERE IS THE PROBLEM? I cannot observe it. The builder seems to work fine

Comment: @Desolator: pardon me?????

Comment: @Yohan I don't see what is the wrong with the first screen shot.

Comment: @Desolator: ohh. There are only few can answer that. Since Java people are originally from hand code practice, this question will not suit to many. I didn't address any of the user's question, what I did is showing how bad the automated GUI build when it comes to Java.

Comment: @user1617737 The first screen shot is perfect. I don't see any problem and I think the question is meaningless

Comment: @Desolator The problem is that although the full length of the scrollbar is shown, the left hand side of it has been clipped visually. #attentiontodetail !

Comment: @user1617737 Finally got to run the code.  The only time I get this problem is when I use you `getScrollBarForScrollPane`. If I remove it, it works fine

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not for me...

Comment: @user1617737 It's the only thing I changed.  With it, the scroll bar is to wide, without, it's fine...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Looks like I'm a bit behind the times when it comes to how I expect scrollbars to look. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this snapshot [from the reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html), your scroll bar is perfect:
[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The question is a nonsense: the scrollbar IS well drawn. No solution exists for problem which isn't.

Comment: The question was "...p, the JScrollPane displays badly...". It's not true, the JScrollPane is perfectly displayed.

Comment: @Aubin yes there are a few issues, I'm tried to describe only about important ...

Comment: Thanks for this. The scrollbar just looks wrong, like the left hand part of it is missing. Not seen a scrollbar like this before and it doesn't look like this in the Preview Design tool either so I presumed it was a bug.

Comment: I've found the real cause of this issue now. Check out the javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName()); line in the source code - that is what (in my opinion) is resulting in such a naff scrollbar.

Comment: With reference to the source code, I have commented out that entire block of code and it looks normal again. Can also change "Nimbus" to "Metal", "CDE/Motif", "Windows" or "Windows Classic"...

Answer (score 1):

1. Swing GUI is correctly builded, meaning methods and code generated by GUI_Builer :-),
2. one of issues is generated from code line `tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{greenIcon, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"});`
3. you added a new row to the `JTable`, to the Swing GUI, after is called `pack()` last code line `pack();` in `initComponents();`,
4. but major issue is that `PreferredSize` is calculated internally from code line `.addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)`, then override this size by using quite proper method `jTable1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(jTable1.getPreferredSize());` is quite pretty ignored
5. write this code by hand

Comment: I really appreciate the 5th suggestion :)

Comment: @Yohan hehehe, but I love all LayoutManagers, doesn't matter if some of them are really crazy and against all logical rulles...