# Netbeans Java GUI Builder - how to prevent pack()?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, builder, pack

I'm building an app with Netbeans GUI Builder, and I want the main JFrame to be maximised, so have set:

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

However, Netbeans calls pack() which results in the JFrame size being reduced. I know I can use the above code again after pack() has been called, but is there anyway I can prevent Netbeans from inserting the pack() line so I can keep my code a bit cleaner?

(Netbeans puts its pack() line in a block that you can't edit, so I can't simply remove it in the usual manner.)

Comment: Given `pack()` ***should*** be called at some stage in the creation of the GUI, you should really be looking at a way to re-order the invocation of the methods, rather than get the JRE to not call `pack()`.

Comment: there is issue with sizing came from built_in GroupLayout, don't to use XxxBuider

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I've just stuck with my original which was just to call setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); after the call to NB's initComponents() method (which included the call to pack()).

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Design" of your JFrame, click on JFrame fmor the Navigator window, then on "Code" in Properties tab click on

> Form Size Policy -> No Resize Code

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for this. This was the kind of answer I was looking for, but when I do what you suggested and run the app, then click the JFrame window's "Restore Down" icon, the window disappears... re Andrew Thompson comment, above.

Comment: What is the "restore down" icon?

Comment: At the top right hand corner of each window on Windows, you have three icons - "Minimize", "Restore Down" and "Close". Restore Down normally reduces the size of the window, but in the case I was reporting, it reduced the size down to zero. :(

Comment: Probably you need to define the minimum/recommended size of the frame ?

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to coerce the GUI designer to do what you want. As an alternative, manage your own top-level container, `Main.JFrame` in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513), and use the designer to manage individual panels.

Answer (score -2):

Probably something with layouts would be better. But my solution: override Window.pack :)

```
@Override
public void pack() {
}
```

Comment: That's a poor 'solution' that will cause two problems for every one it supposedly solves.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thoughtless of ne, appreciated.

Comment: @Joop Eggen agreed with (@Andrew Thompson), not with downvoter, sure/but this is specific issue with GroupLayout, there isn't any chance to re_layout this container, see my [4th. point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15144915/714968), btw I saw that there a few times